# Several div's grouped each on a line

Tags: html, line

I have looked at some examples here and found out how to put, say, three div's on the same line.

When I want the next group of div's on a second line, I run into trouble.

How do I do this?

Here is my code. Where I currently have 
s I want a new line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
#id1 {  
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
  background-color: #33ccff;  
  width: 1000px;  
        height: 500px;
  padding-top: 5px;  
  padding-right: 5px;  
  padding-bottom: 5px;  
  padding-left: 5px;  
  border-top-width: 5px;  
  border-right-width: 5px;  
  border-bottom-width: 5px;  
  border-left-width: 5px;  
  border-top-style: ridge;  
  border-right-style: ridge;  
  border-bottom-style: ridge;  
  border-left-style: ridge;  
  border-top-color: #330033;  
  border-right-color: #330033;  
  border-bottom-color: #330033;  
  border-left-color: #330033;
}

#id2 {  
  font-size: large;  
  font-family: Papyrus;
}

#id9 {  
  font-family: "Arial Narrow";
  min-width: 875px;
}

#id10 {  
  font-family: "Arial Narrow";
  float:left;
}

#id11 {  
  min-width: 875px;
}

</style> </head>
  <body>
    <div id="id1"> <br>
      <br>
      <div id="id9">
        <div id="id10" style="width:180px;"> <b>Last name: </b> ....</div>
        <div id="id10" style="width:200px;"> <b>First name :</b> .... </div>
        <div id="id10" style="width:200px;"> <b>Middle name :</b> .... </div>
        <div id="id10" style="width:200px;"> <b>Referral #: </b>....</div>
      </div><br>
      <div id="id11">
        <div id="id10" style="width:100px;"> <b> SSN: .... </b></div>
        <b>
          <div id="id10" style="width:150px;"> <b>Date of Birth: </b>.... </div>
          <div id="id10" style="width:50px;"> <b>Age </b>..... </div>
          <div id="id10" style="width:150px;"> <b>Gender: </b>.... </div>
          <div id="id10" style="width:100px;"> <b>Ethnicity: </b>.... </div>
        </b></div>
   <br>
        <div id="id9">
          <div id="id10" style="width:100px;"> <b>Address: </b>.... </div>
          <div id="id10" style="width:350px;"> .... </div>
          <div id="id10" style="width:150px;"> <b>City: </b>.... </div>
          <div id="id10" style="width:200px;"> <b>Zip: </b> .... <b> - </b>
            .... </div>
          <div id="id10" style="width:50px;"> <b>State: </b> .... </div>
          <div id="id10" style="width:350px;"> <b>Phone #: (</b> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use table instead of div for these cases.

Comment: Using tables for layout is *ugly* and non-semantic and should be crushed!

Comment: I tried tables, but it gets too difficult to control positions of the fields when the number of fields and their lengths change widely. In the actual code I have PHP commands injected where "..."s are.

Comment: Seems like I may have found an answer: When id9 gets the "float:left", the problem goes away...

Answer (score 1):

I will use CSS display:inline on the div elements you want to display in a line.

[See live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/twxMn/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">

#id10 {
    display: inline;
}

div{
    border: solid 1px gray;
}

</style> </head>
  <body>
    <div id="id1"> 
      <div id="id9">
        <div id="id10" style="width:180px;"> <b>Last name: </b> ....</div>
        <div id="id10" style="width:200px;"> <b>First name :</b> .... </div>
        <div id="id10" style="width:200px;"> <b>Middle name :</b> .... </div>
        <div id="id10" style="width:200px;"> <b>Referral #: </b>....</div>
      </div>
    <br>
      <div id="id11">
        <div id="id10" style="width:100px;"> <b> SSN: .... </b></div>
        <b>
          <div id="id10" style="width:150px;"> <b>Date of Birth: </b>.... </div>
          <div id="id10" style="width:50px;"> <b>Age </b>..... </div>
          <div id="id10" style="width:150px;"> <b>Gender: </b>.... </div>
          <div id="id10" style="width:100px;"> <b>Ethnicity: </b>.... </div>
        </b>
        </div>
   <br>
        <div id="id9">
          <div id="id10" style="width:100px;"> <b>Address: </b>.... </div>
          <div id="id10" style="width:350px;"> .... </div>
          <div id="id10" style="width:150px;"> <b>City: </b>.... </div>
          <div id="id10" style="width:200px;"> <b>Zip: </b> .... <b> - </b>
            .... </div>
          <div id="id10" style="width:50px;"> <b>State: </b> .... </div>
          <div id="id10" style="width:350px;"> <b>Phone #: (</b> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This looks like an elegant solution.

Comment: I just tried yours. It does indeed put fields on lines, but it ignores the "width" parameters. Is there a way to get solve that?